# How to Count each digit occurrence in a given table filed in SQL?

Tags: sql, vertica

How can i count each digit occurence in a given filed and insert in a seperate column sql or vertica SQL.

below is the example. Tab1 table is having ac_number column.

```
Tab1 

ac_number    
12344665533334    
12304885577339


Tab2
c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9
0   1  1  5  3  2  2  0  0  0
1   1  1  3  1  2  0  2  2  1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_count()`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/RegularExpressions/REGEXP_COUNT.htm) function:

```
SELECT regexp_count(ac_number, '0') as c0,
    regexp_count(ac_number, '1') as c1,
    etc...
From yourtable;
```